# Why does Tom ask Olympia to cover the lamps at the door?

Tags: bird-box

Tom says to Olympia:

> Tom: There should be two lamps on either side of the door. I'm gonna
> hand you a blanket and **I want you to drape it across the both of them**.

Why does Tom ask Olympia to cover the lamps at the door?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's some additional dialogue in [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/bird-box-2018.pdf) that didn't make it into the film. The blanket is going to block the light outside, preventing the people inside from being able to see out (and presumably potentially seeing a nasty)

> **GREG:** *Oh for god’s sake, let her in.*
>
> [But Tom advances, grabbing a blanket from the back of the
> sofa on his way--]
>
> **TOM:** *Wait, hang on.*
> (through door)
> *I’m going to open the door just a little and hand you a blanket. There are two porch lamps on either side of the door, you need to hang this on ‘em **to block the view, okay?***
>
> **OLYMPIA** (O.S.) *Okay*.
>
> **TOM** (to room) *Look away*.
>
> [They obey, as Tom opens the door a crack and tosses the blanket outside, then closes it again.]